# SAS : proc freq on 3 categorical variables

Tags: sas

I have data with

- One binary variable, *poor*
- Two socio-demographic variables *var1* and *var2*

I would like to have the poverty rate of each of my *var1* * *var2* possible value, that would look like that :

[image]

But with three variables in a proc freq, I get multiple outputs, one for each value of the first variable I put on my product

```
proc freq data=test;
table var1*var2*poor;
run;
```

How can I get something close to what I would like ?

Comment: Check out PROC TABULATE. Do you want just the frequency counts or percentages as well?

Comment: I would rather have the pourcentages only. I want to know the poverty rate in each of my *var1* * *var2* value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    data test;
    input var1 var2 poor;
    cards;

    1 1 1
    2 3 0
    3 2 1
    4 1 1
    1 2 1
    2 3 0
    4 1 0
    4 2 0
    3 1 1
    1 2 0
    3 2 0
    1 3 1
    3 3 0
    3 3 0
    3 3 1
    1 1 0
    2 2 0
    2 2 1
    2 2 1
    2 1 1
    2 1 1
    2 1 1

    ;
run;


proc tabulate data=test;
class var1 var2 poor;
tables var1,
       var2*poor*pctn<poor>={label="%"};
run;
```